# iPhone app having bugs on app-store version but not ad-hoc distribution

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, adhoc

The AppStore version of my iOS app has some bugs that I could not reproduce on Ad Hoc and debug mode, even when I use the same archive for both.

According to the accepted answer from  [Bug Appears in Distribution (App Store) Version of iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054949/bug-appears-in-distribution-app-store-version-of-iphone-app), I changed the Optimization Level to **Fastest, Smallest** but still can't reproduce the bug.

Anyone knows what makes the real difference between AdHoc and AppStore distribution in this case ?

**UPDATE**:
I managed to reproduce the issue on simulator with debug mode, the bug was related to this line of code:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"article" ofType:@"html"]]]];
```

The bug is fixed on simulator if replacing that line with:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"article" ofType:@"html"]]]];
```

However, fixing the bug on simulator doesn't ensure that there's no issue on real devices. And the question still remains, how to reproduce the bug in the first place with Ad-hoc distribution and Debug mode ?

Comment: It seems [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211486/solved-peculiar-problem-iphone-application-distribution-build-contains-a-bug) tells to set the **"Optimization Level"** to **"None"** instead of "Fastest, Smallest"

Comment: The **"Optimization Level"** was **"None"** by default, I didn't see the bug with that setting.

Comment: @EmptyStack, btw I think the solution you mentioned is changing the Optimization Level of **release mode** to Fastest, Smallest which I don't think is recommended.

Comment: Alright. Sorry. I think I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Are you reproducing AppStore version bugs yourself with the same device or reading crash-reports ? If latter, it might be related to the devices configuration.

Comment: @A-Live, there was no crash, it just that some functions don't work properly (e.g. some embeded HTML files weren't loaded in app-store distribution). We are testing on multiple devices, all have the same problem (working fine with Ad-hoc distribution, but not the App-store one)

Comment: I would use any iPhone browsing utility (like iExplorer) to make sure the files you've mentioned are included into installed AppStore app bundle. It doesn't really look like a code related issue.

Comment: @A-Live: thanks, I will check with iExplorer. However, it seems to be a code related issue, see update in my question.