# iOS5, popover loses its height

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have an Ipad app what has multiple OpenGL tile images, couple buttons in the corners, one of which opens a popover view.
 The app have been tested with no issues on several devices with different iOS versions on them, running straight from Xcode as well as using binary build. After all the testing it was submitted to the app store. And now, after downloading it from the app store on the ipad 2 with iOS5 there's a weird behavior with the popover view. After opening and closing the popover view twice, if you try to open it 3rd time the popover view loses its height and looks like this:

[image]

Also as you can see it doesn't point at the button that opens it anymore. The popover stays like this until you restart the app.
In the devices with iOS older than iOS5 everything is working fine. So the bug shows up only on iOS5 and only when you download the app from the app store.

Did anyone see a similar popover behavior? And is there any way to fix it?

Also any ideas on what can cause a bug to appear only in the app store app? Last question: any ideas on next steps if we can demonstrate the bug only occurs once the app has been submitted? Contact Apple?

Thanks so much for your help and I'd be happy to provide any additional details to get this resolved. Thank you again.

Comment: The contents of the popover, is it a UIViewController?  And if so, are you implementing the contentSizeForViewInPopover method?  If it is, and you are not, I would try to implement contentSizeForViewInPopover with a fixed size to see if it displays the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will definitely try it. I set the size like this 'popViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    popoverController.popoverContentSize = size;
    
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:rootView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];'

Comment: I also found this interesting post what can be related to my problem [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211486/solved-peculiar-problem-iphone-application-distribution-build-contains-a-bug

Comment: I'm curious whether you tested it in an ad hoc distribution? If so, I assume you didn't see this happen, or you didn't try it with an iOS 5 device? (Just wondering if ad hoc fails to show some problems.)

Comment: Tested with Ad Hoc and Dev Profiles on ipad2 with iOS 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for a long delay.

The problem was that my client built a binary for submission on the older version of the xcode and basically lied about it. After resubmitting it properly bug disappeared.